# How to provide bot AppId in azure bot service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

How to provide AppId in Azure Bot service. Going ahead all Microsoft bot framework application will be in Azure bot service. In dev portal of Microsoft bot framework we could provide the app Id while create a Bot application. How can we follow the same method in Azure Bot service?

Answer (score 3):

For "Web App Bot" and "Functions Bot" you can find the MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftAppPassword for your bot in the Application Settings blade in the Azure portal. More info in the article [Manage a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-manage-overview).

The Bot Channels Registration bot service comes with a MicrosoftAppID but because there is no app service associated with this type of service, there is no Application Settings blade for you to look up the MicrosoftAppPassword. To get the password, you must go generate one. To generate the password for a Bot Channels Registration, see Bot Channels Registration password article here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart-registration#bot-channels-registration-password